# darkstat shown blocked traffic

Tags: iptables, qemu, traffic

I've installed Darkstat on a Qemu VM which is connected to a bridge interface on top of main server's interface ( eth0 )
In Darkstat report I can see many hosts in the same IP range of specified VMs are transferring packets with VM while I've blocked all of them in forward chain of Iptables,
Any one familiar with this kind of issue? any advise on how can that packets bypassing the Iptables?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, Darkstat is showing traffic rightfully, 
The problem was because of insecure network many packets from other IPs are being forwarded to my VM and this make Darkstat to show that IPs are transferring with my VM, Darkstat is right they are transferring data to my VM but noy my IP.